# Copy new table column entries between 2 databases and delete them after

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-insert, corresponding-records

I'm using an SQL Server 2000.

We have a live database with over 10gb of data. I want to create a new backup database which is was easy to do. so after creating my new backup database I want to create based on time (eg. 1 day) a query or a procedure to copy new data from live database to backup database.

```
Live_Database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....)
Backup_Database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....)
```

So, I need to update records on Backup_database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....) from Live_database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....).

After updating the records in Backup_Database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....) i want to delete records in Live_database(Table1, Table2, Table3.....) where record_id from table1 from Live_database is older than x days.

Comment: Why you need to create the BackupDatabse? What is the final purpose you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to empty the live database because our system that people uses is loading the whole database. if database is 20gb then our program is loading the whole database into the pc. and the old pc cannot load any more, just the new pc with big ram can use the program

Comment: What method your program is using to load the whole database? Is it execute simple SELECT statements directly against the database TABLEs from code?

Comment: i really don't know how the program is running or using. the program has been made by smbd and we don't have the source code of it. we even tried to run it on a sql 2005 but it does not work. it was programmed specific for sql 2000.